# How to append data in second ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have 2 ajax, one is fine to show data. But, in second, it's give nothing.

I've already tried to append to some element, and it's the same result, nothing showed.

```
$(function () {
            // Hide Loader [ Default ]
            $('#loading-projects').hide()
            $('#loading-tasks').hide()

            $.ajax({
                url: 'SomeApiURL',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // Show Loader
                    $('#loading-projects').show()
                },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Hide Loader
                    $('#loading-projects').fadeOut('slow')
                    var html_holder = ''
                        $.each(data.projects, function(key, project) {
                            html_holder += '<div class="container-fluid">'
                                // Box Head
                                html_holder += '<div class="box box-solid box-primary">'
                                    html_holder += '<div class="box-header" id="panel-head">'
                                        html_holder += '<div class="box-title">'    
                                            html_holder += project.name + ' - ' + project.id
                                            html_holder += '<a style="margin-left: 10px;" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-target="#collapseDiv' + key + '"><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>'
                                        html_holder += '</div>'
                                    html_holder += '</div>'

                                    // Box body
                                    html_holder += '<div id="collapseDiv' + key + '" class="">'
                                        html_holder += '<div class="panel-body isi">'


                                            // Get Tasks
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    url: 'SomeApiURL',
                                                    type: 'GET',
                                                    beforeSend: function() {
                                                        $('#loading-tasks').show()
                                                    },
                                                    success: function(tasks) {
                                                        $('#loading-tasks').fadeOut()
                                                        $.each(tasks['todo-items'], function(key, task) {
                                                            if(project.id == task['project-id']) {
                                                                html_holder += task.content
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                })
                                            // End Get Tasks
                                        html_holder += '</div>'
                                    html_holder += '</div>'
                                html_holder += '</div>'
                            html_holder += '</div>'
                        })
                    $('#project-list').append(html_holder)
                }
            })
        })
```

I just want to append task.content in the body, but it gives nothing.

Thanks by the way.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. Therefore you cannot use ajax to intersect strings. You'll be better off rewriting your logic where you can use DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: It somehow looks like you are calling the 2nd ajax call for each of your projects, but fetch ALL tasks everytime. Or why are you checking if the project ids match ? As Cue said, the only way to concatenate a string is with a synchronous task, you could make your ajax call `async = false` but this will end up in a horrific user experience. You should instead either insert the tasks into your project data or make a single call after your project data is completly done and then run through your dom and insert the tasks data at the right places

Comment: @Lapskaus , yes i must using condition.. where some task is assign to some project. And i want to append the task in the right projects,

Comment: My question is why though, if you are looping through each project and you fetch data based on the projects data your ajax call should never return anything not related to the current project in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous. Therefore you cannot use ajax to intersect strings. You'll be better off rewriting your logic where you can use DOM manipulation instead.

For example...

- Continue using nested requests but reinvent the logic to navigate the DOM in the requests beyond the parent
- Using template literals for better string interpolation when building HTML strings
- Using something unique such as `project.id` to help identify your DOM elements inside subsequent requests

```
const tasksLoader = $('#loading-tasks').hide();
const projectsLoader = $('#loading-projects').show(); // no reason to hide since you're immediately showing before request

$.get('/api/endpoint1', (data) => {
  projectsLoader.fadeOut('slow');
  let htmlstr;
  data.projects.forEach((project) => {
    htmlstr = `
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
          <div class="box-header" id="panel-head">
            <div class="box-title">
              ${project.name} - ${project.id}
              <a style="margin-left: 10px;" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-target="#collapseDiv${project.id}"><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseDiv${project.id}">
            <div class="panel-body isi"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    $('#project-list').append(htmlstr);
  });

  tasksLoader.show();
  $.get('/api/endpoint2', (tasks) => {
    $('#loading-tasks').fadeOut();
    let projectId, projectElement;
    tasks['todo-items'].forEach((task) => {
      projectId = task['project-id'];
      projectElement = $(`#collapseDiv${projectId}`);
      if (projectElement.length) {
        projectElement.find('.panel-body').html(task.content)
      } else {
        console.log(`Cannot add task to project [${projectId}] element does not exist.`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. can I ask?, what's the different between using ajax and $.http request?, i will implement the code tomorrow, it's midnight in here by the way, hahaha.

Comment: `.get` is a shorthand method for GET requests instead of using `.ajax`. You can read more about it in the jQuery docs.

Comment: Oh, okay. Can I include some headers object?, for authorization / basic auth in there?, i forgot to paste the headers.

Comment: Yes, you can use `$.get({ ... })`. All options available in `$.ajax` can be applied here too.

Comment: Okay then, thanks for the help, I will note it., it's midnight by the way in here, I will implement the code tomorrow, good night mate.